# Report group headings not repeating on every page

Tags: reporting-services

I have an RDLC report with three tables and associated data sets.  In my second table, I cannot get the two 'header' rows to repeat on each printed page.  When viewed interactively, each table is on its own page and this isn't a problem.  When I switch to print layout, e.g. my second table now spans two pages, and the second page gets no header rows.

Am I missing a setting or something?

ADDED: I do have the 'Repeat Header columns on each page' checked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/06/14/what-to-do-when-the-repeatcolumnheaders-property-in-a-tablix-isn-t-working.aspx

That should help you out for getting them to repeat. (some of the time)

I still have an issue where I set the hidden value to an expression for the next group header that some of the time it won't render my group header on the next page.  Very annoying.  If someone knows of a fix for this please let me know.

Comment: Amazing that you have to expose an "Advanced" menu item for something as basic as repeating column headers on each new page...  Dooohhhh.

Comment: To summarize the answer from this link. ***Column Group > Advanced. Row Group > "Static" (above desired group). Static group properties changes (KeepWithGroup = After, FixedData = True, RepeatOnNewPage = True)***

Answer (score 12):

Copied from [Microsoft Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207045.aspx). Helped me:

**To display a static tablix member (row or column) on multiple pages.**

1. On the design surface, click the row or column handle of the tablix data region to select it. The Grouping pane displays the row and column groups.
2. On the right side of the Grouping pane, click the down arrow, and then click Advanced Mode.  The Row Groups pane displays the hierarchical static and dynamic members for the row groups hierarchy and the Column groups pane shows a similar display for the column groups hierarchy.
3. Click the static member that corresponds to the static member (row or column) that you want to remain visible while scrolling. The Properties pane displays the Tablix Member properties.
4. In the Properties pane, set RepeatOnNewPage to True.
5. Repeat this for as many adjacent members as you want to repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ticked "Repeat header rows on each page" on the table properties?

(Right-click the table > properties)

Comment: @ProfK - How are you printing the report - direct from the interactive view, or via a non-interactive renderer (like PDF)?

Comment: @Ed, until now I have not had a chance to actually print the report.  I have just been viewing it in the WinForms viewer.  I'll report back on actual printing later today.