# Hi i need the solution for this SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table in SSRS which is grouped and the problem is one of the row has huge data and the  content of which is flowing to next pages and the border is not coming at the bottom and the header is also not coming to those pages ....

how can i get the bottom border for that overflowed row and the header..?????

Comment: I had a reporting experience with Access and Crystal report. I think you should use the `[keep-together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255248.aspx)` option.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416326/report-group-headings-not-repeating-on-every-page

Comment: Great title. Why don't we use it for every question related to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Is it martix or tablix????
If it is matrix goto the Tablix properties and follow the instructions below                 RowHaders:Select Repeat headers rows and keep headers visible while scrolling              Column Headers :      Select Repeat headers columns and keep headers visible while Scrolling
and remove the page breakes if any.....

Comment: its in tablix not tablix and have tried with keep headers visible while scrolling Column Headers and  Repeat headers columns and keep headers visible while Scrolling and there is no page break too... but not working

Comment: is that problem with column names or header and footer? If it is about page header and footer Can you please explain me what are you trying show in the page header and footer.

Comment: its the problem with table header since one of the row has huge data and the row is breaking to next pages about 4 to 5, where only the continued values of row is displaying which d'nt have table header and

Comment: and since the content of the row is breaking there is no bottom line or border to that table in the page