# Repeat report group header on every pages even if group footer is alone on the page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a simple SSRS report like this:

```
Group Header
------------------------
Group Detail
------------------------
Group Footer
```

I configured the header to repeat on every new page like described in this question: [Report group headings not repeating on every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416326/report-group-headings-not-repeating-on-every-page)

But sometimes, the detail section arrives just at the bottom of a page and the part that gets pushed to the following page is the group footer, and unfortunately the group header does not get repeated on that page.

My question: is there a way to set up the group header so it appears on every pages even when the only thing on the page is the group footer?

Note: I don't think I can move it to the *report* header as this *group* header has summary data.

**Edit:** I realized I wasn't clear on 1 point: I would like the group header to be *before* the group footer on that following page. To recap: 1st page would have group header + detail, and 2nd page group header + group footer. This off course only if there is not enough space for group footer on 1st page.

Comment: Do you have a page break between the groups (or after or before)?

Comment: Page break is set to: between each instance of a group

Comment: Remove the page break. Page Break is the reason as soon as the group footer comes, it pushes the next group header to new page. Also look into `KeepTogether` property.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't precise enough. Please see my edit