# Needing to Display Multiple Rows Per Page in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs-2008-r2

I've got a report that I would like to display the first three rows on all pages of the report. I have got the first row repeating on each page, but I am having trouble with the second and third rows - they will not repeat for some reason.

Here is where I have gone into the Advanced Mode and selected the Static grouping for the first cell in the first row:

[image: Repeat Row 1]

And in the Properties windows, I have selected KeepWithGroup = After and RepeatOnNewPage = True.

When I run the report, the top line appears on each page of the report.

I would also like the second and third lines to repeat, so I did the same thing for each of these rows. In the Advanced Mode, I selected the Static  grouping for each of the rows and changed the KeepWithGroup = After and RepeatOnNewPage = True.

Since I am doing some grouping on the report, I tried two different static groups to get it working, one in the TWRA Number cell and one in the First Name cell.

[image: 2nd Line A]
[image: 2nd Line B]

And finally, I wanted the row with the headers for Date, License Type, License Description, etc. to repeat so I selected the Static grouping for the third line and it highlighted the first cell in the row and I made the Advanced Mode properties changes there:

[image: 3rd Line]

I've tried different variations for KeepWithGroup to be After or Before, but nothing will make the second and third lines repeat.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It depends on your luck, if it is working. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416326/report-group-headings-not-repeating-on-every-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right mouse click TWRANumber field, Insert Row - Inside Group Above, Cut and paste the first row onto the new second row.

Delete the old first row.

This should help you.

Comment: Thanks Phillip - I'll try this out.